# "Convert" zlib stream to gzip?

Tags: shell, gzip, zlib

I have a blob of data which is compressed with zlib, now I need to decompress it but only have gzip at hand in a Linux environment. No possibility of getting any other tools unfortunately. Is there any way to "convert" the zlib data into something that gzip can decompress?

I read this one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22834/how-to-uncompress-zlib-data-in-unix

Where it's basically said to add a 10 bytes header and pass it into gzip. However, when I try this I don't get any output. The out file is empty.

```
printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" |cat - /tmp/data |gzip -dc >/tmp/out
```

/tmp/data contains a chunk of data that starts with these two bytes: \x78\xDA (which I interpret as a zlib header).

Any suggestions? I've also tried removing these 2 bytes before prepending the gzip header.

Edit:
After some more thinking and after reading the comments here I realized that the input data was in fact not correct. Using another source for test data I got a bit further. See below, encoded as base64 since I could not attach binary data.

I have the source data:

```
eJwNzbEvA1EcwPEcgsUs6UIisZ17v7tre2ehaR+Kq/TaU0XEvddTd9yrtq8NFiQ1GGwisWnSQQSJwWoSJgMWxGBCYvEPEB2/y+f7WIvWhf5629jWXE/ShJ/erNDVEEgMtwXIydZ9e2DxbtLQhda60LCrO6eEuuuSZSYGrelofBBBDEvxWZAVNRiRZMBofCYWtpLZEI5OGkomHc6O9GmEFpoeybEWkuOejGQQkSoiIG6ZmwXilHjvRIEui3FW5i6vcOLb/pQ5KgJCSAHQVOKvrWJLAklGEgRRmJRzLYTnXU1FQUVHKESqax4A6IrarDDNFYgHeqj50ESQKbP9BllinlEpc6fk24yRPHNwyV2x6RLjnmGl0tg0IokEzTPuYDM+EaFVp+TAABpAM8Pjtcc9u/PrYdHJFK+f37vfAocdmxf5s5uUmJ73Lz86F/z93233c+P1++mlOPR369GrVqzvnh8dH95qB/QfS/18rQ==
```

Then I strip the two first bytes, which gives me this:

```
Dc2xLwNRHMDxHILFLOlCIrGde7+7a3tnoWkfiqv02lNFxL3XU3fcq7avDRYkNRhsIrFp0kEEicFqEiYDFsRgQmLxDxAdv8vn+1iL1oX+etvY1lxP0oSf3qzQ1RBIDLcFyMnWfXtg8W7S0IXWutCwqzunhLrrkmUmBq3paHwQQQxL8VmQFTUYkWTAaHwmFraS2RCOThpKJh3OjvRphBaaHsmxFpLjnoxkEJEqIiBumZsF4pR470SBLotxVuYur3Di2/6UOSoCQkgB0FTir61iSwJJRhIEUZiUcy2E511NRUFFRyhEqmseAOiK2qwwzRWIB3qo+dBEkCmz/QZZYp5RKXOn5NuMkTxzcMldsekS455hpdLYNCKJBM0z7mAzPhGhVafkwAAaQDPD47XHPbvz62HRyRSvn9+73wKHHZsX+bOblJie9y8/Ohf8/d9t93Pj9fvppTj0d+vRq1as754fHR/eagf0H0v9fK0=
```

Writing that (in binary, not base64 - just to be clear) to a file: /tmp/inputdata I run the following shell command:

`printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" |cat - /tmp/inputdata| gzip -dc >/tmp/out`

Which gives me this:

```
gzip: corrupted data
```

The contents of /tmp/out (again, base64 encoded):

```
0oRDoQEmoQRIf1sfUVIx8CBZAQ2kAWJERQQaYqh/zQYaYMdMTTkBA6EBpGF2gapiY2l4L1VSTjpVVkNJOjAxREUvSVoxMjM0NUEvMjFFMEpYRDdVUVk2RUNMTTNXVDdZRiM4YmNvYkRFYmRuAmJkdGoyMDIxLTA0LTAxYmlzdFJvYmVydCBLb2NoLUluc3RpdHV0Ym1hbU9SRy0xMDAwMzExODRibXBsRVUvMS8yMC8xNTA3YnNkAmJ0Z2k4NDA1MzkwMDZidnBqMTExOTM0OTAwN2Nkb2JqMTk2NC0wOC0xMmNuYW2kYmZuak11c3Rlcm1hbm5iZ25lRXJpa2FjZm50ak1VU1RFUk1BTk5jZ250ZUVSSUtBY3ZlcmUxLjAuMFhASoTSiWEI6NFgZVdxvtjgF9walgd6rmesxFMtVFxtseYIXm2N/YBp53na69PZcT/+xmpjtQNFOYWtmaCWxjiUYw==
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] that lets someone observe with their own eyes the code from the linked [unix.se] answer not working? Right now, only someone with the same `/tmp/data` you have (which you aren't sharing) can reproduce this.

Comment: Also -- if this is a Linux environment, don't you have Python? Can't you use the Python standard library's `zlib` module to do the decompression?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy after further investigation it seems that the input was not correct to begin with. After getting another sample I found that it seems to work better. Sorry for not providing a sample, wasn't sure I could attach files here.

And regarding Python, no unfortunately this is a very limited embedded Linux environment with limited ways of adding stuff.

Comment: I get "unexpected end of file" with your input, not "corrupted data". Your zlib stream is fine, and indeed decompresses to your `/tmp/out` result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it right. Strip the first two bytes and prepend those ten bytes. Then `gzip -dc` will complain about an "unexpected end of file", but it will nevertheless decompress and write the result to your output file.

Unless the zlib stream is corrupt to begin with.

Comment: wow, your comment made me try another sample which turned out to work. It seems that the input I had was not correct... After trying another sample I got the "corrupted data" error, but it still gave me output which looks OK so far. Any idea (without seeing the input and output) why it gives me that error? Is it because of the lac of the trailing part with some checksum or similar? Will try to attach some sample data to this thread...